# How to get sbt to stop trying to pull latest transitive range dependency on each build

Tags: scala, sbt

We are using a library that depends on Amazon's Kinesis client.  The client library itself has a transitive 'range' dependency on a number of aws core libraries.

Unfortunately, our build/update has slowed down significantly since we started using this library.  Is there a way to tell sbt to use a specific version without checking if that is the latest every time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you're dealing with Ivy's [dynamic revisions feature](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html), you have two problems to contend with:

1. slow builds due to dependency resolution taking a very long time, and
2. your builds are no longer reproducible.

Although you don't mention it in your question, I think this second problem is the more serious of the two so let's consider it first. Irreproducible builds are something that [Havoc Pennington has written about](https://blog.ometer.com/2017/01/10/dear-package-managers-dependency-resolution-results-should-be-in-version-control/):

> If your build depends on a non-exact dependency version (like
>   “somelibrary >= 3.1”), and the exact version gets recomputed every
>   time you run the build, your project is *broken*.
>
> - You can no longer build old versions and get the same results.
> - Want to cut a bugfixes-only release from an old branch? Sorry.
> - Want to use git bisect? Nope.
> - You can’t rely on your code working because it will change by itself. Maybe it worked today, but that doesn’t mean it will work
>     tomorrow. Maybe it worked in continuous integration, but that doesn’t
>     mean it will work when deployed.
>     Wondering whether any dependency versions changed and when? No way to figure it out.
>
> Package management and build tools should get this right by default.
>   It is a *real* problem; I’ve seen it bite projects I’m working on
>   countless times.

He goes on to say:

> What’s the solution? I’d argue that it’s been well-known for a while.
>   Persist the output of the dependency resolution process and keep it in
>   version control.

This is exactly what npm's [package-lock.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) and yarn's [yarn.lock](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock) try to achieve. So, does sbt have an equivalent feature? Not really. It's [on their radar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/wiki/User-Stories:--Offline-mode-and-Dependency-Locking#the-dependency-lockfile), but there's nothing like a lockfile available out of the box as of sbt 0.13.15.

What can we do? We could add dependency overrides for specific versions of each of our transitive dependencies. Let's pick on the jQuery UI bower WebJar as an example. Imagine you have this in your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery-ui" % "1.12.1"
```

If you look at [its pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/bower/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui-1.12.1.pom) you'll see it has a dependency on jQuery with a version range of `[1.6,)`. We could lock this range down to a specific version by adding an override like this to our build.sbt:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.webjars.bower" % "jquery" % "3.2.1"
```

This is probably tolerable for our jQuery UI example, but as our list of dependencies grows, it becomes boring and error prone to do this manually. What is the complete list of dependencies? Which versions should we use as overrides?

Fortunately, there's an sbt plugin called [sbt-lock](https://github.com/tkawachi/sbt-lock) that will take care of it for you. Quoting from sbt-lock's README:

> Add the following line to `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/sbt-lock.sbt` or
>   `project/plugins.sbt`.
>
> `addSbtPlugin("com.github.tkawachi" % "sbt-lock" % "0.3.0")`
>
> `lock` to create `lock.sbt` file. lock.sbt includes dependencyOverrides for all dependent library versions. Manage it with
>   version control system.
>       `unlock` to delete `lock.sbt` file.

So we've solved the problem of irreproducible builds, but does this improve the build time? I was hoping it would but it looks like it doesn't. I was hoping sbt would notice the dependency overrides and not bother to do the (now unnecessary) expensive dependency resolution, but it looks like it does the expensive resolution anyway (and *then* overrides the result of the expensive resolution).

So we need a bigger hammer. The only solution I'm aware of is to spin up a local Nexus repository, configure it as a proxy/cache for all the repos your build requires (Maven Central, etc) and then force your sbt build to use this (and *only* this) local Nexus to resolve dependencies. This approach is something that [Timothy Perrett wrote about](http://timperrett.com/2015/12/20/optiomizing-sbt-resolution-times) a couple of years ago (emphasis mine):

> In many Scala project builds - regardless of if its on travis-ci.org,
>   on-premise[s] Jenkins or otherwise - a large portion of the overall build
>   time is spent in doing dependency resolution. *This is further
>   aggravated when builds used Ivy's dynamic revision feature*, as updates
>   need to be calculated for each build, regardless of the Ivy local
>   cache.

He lists the following steps (read his whole post for more details):

1. [Install a local Nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install.html). On macOS I use Homebrew and `brew install nexus`.
2. [Set up proxy repos](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html).
3. [Configure sbt to use the proxy repos](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) (in file `$HOME/.sbt/repositories`).
4. Configure sbt to use *only* the repos defined in `$HOME/.sbt/repositories`. He lists a few ways to achieve this. Read his post and the  [proxy repos section of the sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) for more details and motivation.

An alternative to spinning up a local Nexus might be to use [sbt's experimental cached resolution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html):

```
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(true)
```

Comment: danielnixon - this is a very thorough breakdown of the problems I am facing.  What's unfortunate is that our dependency is on a single AWS library (kinesis-client) that pulls in many ranged AWS dependencies.  I'd be willing to explore using sbt-lock but for all that effort the dependency resolution speed does not improve...

Comment: Might be worth investigating: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cached-Resolution.html